# Не могу понять где ошибка

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
def funct(**number):
    for key in sorted(number.keys()):
        print(number[key])

funct(2, 3, 4, 5, 6)
```

Ошибка:

```
TypeError: funct() takes 0 positional arguments but 5 were given
```

Comment: Для начала почитайте для чего в Python используют `*args` и `**kwargs`

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 5):

`**` означает, что ожидаются именованные параметры функции.

```
def funct(**number):
    for key in sorted(number.keys()):
        print(number[key])

# Правильно так:
funct(a=2, b=3, c=4, d=5, e=6)

# А можно и так:
d = {'a': 2, 'b': 3, 'c': 4, 'd': 5, 'e': 6}
funct(**d)
```

Результат:

```
2
3
4
5
6
```

Comment: Не позиционные, а именованные ИМХО. Позиционные - это ж вроде как раз таки `*args`

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2/faq/programming.html#how-can-i-pass-optional-or-keyword-parameters-from-one-function-to-another - "keyword parameters".

Comment: Опечатался, сейчас подправлю